# input in floating div with full width in table header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with input width when padding from sides is applied.

I need for input width 100% and padding from sides. But I need to get this div with input next to the div with text "Name". This is what I have right now. All this is for filtering header of table. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

```css
.right{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
}
.left{
    background:green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}
.form-control{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.wrap{
  width: 235px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<th class="wrap">

<div class="left">Name</div>
<div class="right"><input type="text" class="form-control" value=""></div>

</th>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gvgLsryr/1/)

Comment: please edit the question to include the code inline

Comment: What do you mean with `I need to get this div with input next to the div with text "Name"`? the input is next to name div

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use `float`? Have you tried to use `inline-block` instead or remove `float` from the `.right` class?

Answer (score 0):

Give your .left and .right class some width.

```
.left{
    width:20%;
 }

.right{
    width:70%;
   }
```